# How could i set the value from a function in django

Tags: python, django, function

I am developing a little project in django, i am new with this amazing framework. My question is:

There is a way to set a value from my database from a function, there is a example:

I am trying to modify the existencia to False with this:

```
def delete_clasification(request, id_category):
   clasificacion = Clasificacion.objects.get(id=id_category)
   if clasificacion.existencia == True:
       clasificacion.existencia = False
   return redirect('adminview:clasification')
```

But i think this is not the correct way to do it.

This is my url:

```
url(r'^delete_clasification/(?P<id_category>\d+)/$', delete_clasification, name='delete_clasification'),
```

I am just trying that when i go to that url, the value from "clasificacion.existencia" change to False, and just that...

If you can help me with this thing, i appreciate.

Thank you!

Comment: So what is your problem? Is it that the url is throwing an error, or the object value is not being updated? Please state your problem specifically.

Comment: Well basically is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there!!!

After assigning the new value, you have to call the **`save()`** method as below

```
def delete_clasification(request, id_category):
    clasificacion = Clasificacion.objects.get(id=id_category)
    if clasificacion.existencia == True:
        clasificacion.existencia = False
        clasificacion.save() # change is here <<<<<
    return redirect('adminview:clasification')
```

**NOTE:** the attribute **`existencia`** should be a DB field/Model field of your **`Clasificacion`** model